# Responsive CSS: div too big

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I'm trying to resize my lightbox. But when I use *max-width: 100%* the images are too big ([img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzP59.jpg))  for PC's screen too small for cellphones ([img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLG1U.jpg)). And it's the opposite with *max-width: 50%;* ([img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1ngR.jpg) and [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwHNt.jpg)). What should I do?

CSS:

```
/* The Modal (background) */
#galeria .modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
#galeria .modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 50%;

}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">

  <div class="close-button"><span class="close" id="close-sync">&times;</span></div>
    <div id="sync1" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">
          <img src="assets/img/eventos/16-12-2016/01.JPG">
      </div>
    <div class="item">
          <img src="assets/img/eventos/16-12-2016/02.JPG">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="sync2" class="owl-carousel">
      <div class="item">
          <img src="assets/img/eventos/16-12-2016/01.JPG">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Interesting company name :)

Comment: How about using media queries?

Comment: It's a portuguese name: Fundação Assistencial da Paraíba = Paraiba's Assistencial Foundation.

Paraíba is a Brazilian State.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media):

```css
#galeria .modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
}
/* phone screen width */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #galeria .modal-content {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
/* greater than phone width */
@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
    #galeria .modal-content {
        max-width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked nicely, I'm going to read more about media queries. Thanks.